# Rails Route Redirect Based on Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm working on an app where at the bottom left of user profiles, there is a list of event registrations that the user has created. The links are constructed using the /event/id path, which is now deprecated for Special Events (they use /special-events/id). As a result, links to Special Events in this section of user profiles are now broken.

I need to either create paths that redirect to from /events/id to /special-events/id for any IDs that correspond to Special Events (Event::SpecialEvents), or update the path on that engine to smartly link to /event/id or /special-event/id depending on event type.

I know I can't just create a redirect in the routes file. What's the best way to approach this?

Edit: Here are the current relevant redirects in the routes file -

```
  get 'events/special_events/category/:id', to: redirect { |params, req| category_redirect('special-events', params, req) }
  get 'events/special_events/previous/category/:id', to: redirect { |params, req| category_redirect('special-events/previous', params, req) }
  get 'events/special_events/:id', to: redirect('/special-events/%{id}')
  get 'events/special_events/previous/:id', to: redirect('/special-events/on-demand/%{id}')
```

Comment: Can you provide us with sample code from routes.rb, please?

Comment: Edited the question to include some redirects currently in the routes file.

Comment: I'm considering creating a controller method that would assign a path based on event type.